# MPEG2 TS end-to-end delay

Tags: mpeg

I need to calculate the end to end delay (between the encoder and the decoder) in an MPEG 2 TS
based on time stamps information (PTS PCR DTS). Are those time stamps enough to calculate the delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These time-stamps are inserted into the transport stream by the encoder, and are used by the decoder - such as syncing between audio and video frames, and in general locking with the original clock to display the video correctly.

The delay between an encoder and a decoder, on the other hand, is like asking what is the delay between transmitting the data from the source and receiving it in the destination. This is not determined by the data (i.e. the transport stream and the data within such as time stamps) but by the network conditions.